# JS-based pdf report builder (with logic and rich-text)

Tags: javascript, pdf, report, jsreport

I'm willing to make an **easy** to use **web-interfaced report builder**. Basically, I would be like a **big html form** with some **custom logic** (if you check this box then that part of the form appears/disappears), **uploading of images** and **rich text** (bold, italic, colors). The user should be able to **extract a pdf** (that might be either server or client rendered). Some parts of the page should appear in the final pdf, some not. I need to control the page-breaks.

I could build a totally custom web-page for that and plug the result in a custom template in PDFjs, but I was curious if some solutions already exist for this problem. I've looked into [jsreport](https://jsreport.net/) and it's nice, but it is too complicated for my users to edit html directly. I would need more of a wrapper with simple fields. PDF forms, on the other end of the spectrum, are too rigid (an frankly, a pain to deal with) for my use-case.

To me, it feels like this problem is common enough, and should appear in enough companies that **some rich template solution** (or at least, general approach) **might exist somewhere**. Are you aware of such solution ? If not, what general tools would you use ? (PDFjs, Prosemirror, ..)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How much are you willing to spend for infrastructure?

Comment: You mean in terms of time or investment ? Paying for a solution is not what I hoped for (unless an open-sourced one does exactly what I need). In terms of infrastructure, I can have an nodejs based server easily. Thanks for your help :)